# What to do if I mistakenly delete sdk file from a java project

Tags: java, eclipse, sdk

I am new in **Java**. I use **Eclipse** as a IDE.Recently I was working in a **Java project** with some class. But mistakenly I delete the **sdk file** from the project and from then my project is not working. I cannot add the **sdk file** to this project.

What to do now?

Comment: Please add a screenshot. What sdk file are you referring to? The one in your build path?

Comment: Hi Sabab, Whenever I make a big mistake with my project config (Eclipse or IDEA), usually I cannot fix it.  Instead, I create a new project.  Then I copy my source code files from the broken project into the new project.  It's a hassle, but it works.  Good luck!

Comment: Hi _**@devdanke**_, I also do it. But I'm searching a better solution so that I can fixed them. Copying them is not a good solution. But thank you.